# How to locate, link element inside div tag by value using css selector in webdriver?

Tags: selenium

This is code for a button "Signup here" in div tag. I have run this code though Xpath working Fine but I want to alternate method with css selector locator element in selenium Webdriver.

```
<div>
<a href="signup" class="divclass">Signup here</a>
</div>

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='signup']")).‌​click();
```

Comment: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='signup']")).‌​click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of these `CSS` selectors:

```
a[text()="Signup here"]
```

or

```
a.divclass
```

or

```
a[href="signup"]
```

Comment: Hi, it was very helpful for me. but i want use driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(" ")); form. my problem is, what value are put inside " " quotes at based on code.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please accept it with check-mark under upvote/downvote score. Thanks